# Create randomized sets with same set size

Tags: random-generation

An easy example: I have 2 persons. I want to assign them randomized to one of two groups (`1` and `2`). But at the end the groups need to have **the same size** - which means 1 person per group.

I don't know how to realize this concaptualy.

In R I am using

```
library(random)
randomNumbers(n=2, min=1, max=2, col=1)
```

This could be `1 1` or `2 2`. Not good.
What I want is `1 2` or `2 1`.

Of course I will do this with a larger number of objects. And sometimes uneven numbers of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the sample function.

Suppose we have 1000 people

```
nums <- 1:1000
people <- paste("person_",1:1000,sep="")
people
[1] "person_1"    "person_2"    "person_3"    "person_4"    "person_5"   
[6] "person_6"    "person_7"    "person_8"    "person_9"    "person_10"  
[11] "person_11"   "person_12"   "person_13"   "person_14"   "person_15"  
[16] "person_16"   "person_17"   "person_18"   "person_19"   "person_20" 
....
```

We can use the [sample](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) function to define a group, let's call it group A.

```
groupA <- sample(people, length(people)/2, replace = F)
```

Then group B can just be the people not in group A.

```
groupB <- people[!people %in%  groupA]
```

If you have $>2$ groups, you can just do this task sequentially. Suppose we want to separate 900 people into 3 groups. We can do it as such

```
nums <- 1:900
people <- paste("person_",1:900,sep="")

groupA <- sample(people, length(people)/3, replace = F)
groupB <- sample(people[!people %in%  groupA], length(people)/3,
                 replace = F)
groupC <- people[!people %in%  Reduce(union, list(groupA,groupB))]
```

Note: I used the Reduce function because it works well when you want to union more then 2 sets. That way you can generalize easily to more than 3 groups.